# Exporting VS2010 class diagrams to Visio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visio

I am creating class diagram using VS2010. Is there any way to import VS2010 generated class diagrams to import in MS Visio?

Comment: The idea become wonderfull if you want a poster of your data model :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right-click on the class diagram within Visual Studio and select "Export Diagram as Image..."

Choose *Enhanced Metafile Format (*.emf)* which is recognized by Visio.

Comment: Thanks but ... 1 - I couldn't find the 'export' function (VS2012). 2 - Isn't emf a bitmap? If so, would this be importable to Visio?

Comment: @DavidPerlman: I have not got a chance to look at VS2012. If it is an emf it would be a huge benefit.

Comment: I confirm that in visual studio ultimate 2013, there is no `*.emf` option.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no *.emf option in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise either.

Comment: What version is this for. I am using VS pro 2010 and I don't see anything like this.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio 2010 are you using?

Answer (score -3):

You can do it from visual studio
`File > Print` and then send it to OneNote or choose PDF.

Comment: I don't see this option.. for VS Pro 2010. What version are you referencing and simply, File > Print did not work.. I can't even select print when highlighting the class diagram.